# Using Javascript/jQuery to trigger event when textarea rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a JSF page where I'm trying to tie the text in specific paragraphs to the contents of a set of `textarea`s.

Getting the content to change when a `textarea` changes is dirt simple using `onchange` and `onkeyup` events:

```
onchange="$('dynamicParagraphId').text($(this).val());"
```

Unfortunately, I'm having some trouble initializing the paragraphs so that their text matches the `textarea`s when the page is initially loaded.

Because of how the page is implemented, editing the underlying HTML is bloody difficult; I'm not sure how to implement an obvious solution like a script that triggers when the page loads, because it's going to take some real work for me to get a hold of the `textarea`s' IDs.  Is there some way to insert Javascript/jQuery code into the `textarea` definition that will trigger when the page loads so that I can make use of the `this` object and not have to figure out the `textarea` ID?  Is there some feature of jQuery I can leverage that spares me needing to know the IDs?

Comment: Nope. You have to know something about the textarea to select it, such as it's parent, a sibling, it's id or class, any of it's attributes that are unique to the textarea, etc.

Comment: Did you try `$('textarea')`? You will then have all textareas on the page and can go from there...

Comment: can you throw up a brief sample for us to look at?

Comment: You are binding to these events directly from the markup? Use the same function in 'onload'.

Comment: @Malk textareas don't have an onload event.

Comment: How are paragraphs associated to a particular textarea? In other words, how do you know which textarea's text belongs in which paragraph?

Comment: @clav:  The 'dynamicParagraphId' is actually the ID of the paragraph that particular text area is tied to.

Comment: Where does `dynamicParagraphId` come from, how are you assigning the id to each paragraph? Can you post the JSF code?

Answer (score 1):

Trigger the `keyup` event for all textareas, but you can probably come up with a more specific selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("textarea").keyup();
});
```

Or if you can only attach functions through inline markup for some reason you can add it to the `<body>`:

```
<body onload='$("textarea").keyup()'>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many textareas there are and which you want (i.e. the 5th on the page), you could easily query for all textareas:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
```

and select the one you want. Another solution is to hand over the control to JS and render the textarea on the clientside.
http://jsfiddle.net/FExQy/

Comment: Okay, so I CAN give all the textareas I want to behave this way the same class.  But then the problem becomes, how do I find the ID of the paragraph I want that textarea to be tied to?  Is there some way to wildcard the class -- ie, give each textarea a class of "tied-to-paragraph-[PARAGRAPH_ID]", and then get every textarea with a class that begins "tied-to-paragraph-"?

Comment: No. I'd set a data-attribute and pull from there `<textarea data-paragraph="paragraph"></textarea>` then you can use `$('textarea[data-paragraph]')` to get all the textareas that are linked to paragraphs and `.data('paragraph')` to get the value stored for a specific one